# 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable for speaker identification

Tags: python, arrays, loops, speech-recognition

I am working with Gaussian mixture model for speaker identification. I created five GMM for five speakers and getting these type of array for each voice clip:

```
    [ 0.57635198  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
    [ 0.57635198 -8.85254293  0.          0.          0.        ]
    [ 0.57635198 -8.85254293 -5.77808109  0.          0.        ]
    [ 0.57635198 -8.85254293 -5.77808109 -9.19504968  0.        ]
    [ 0.57635198 -8.85254293 -5.77808109 -9.19504968 -9.58078621]

    These output describe the values for a voice clip with each (five) GMM model. Now i decide threshold value for predicting speaker for that i write this code

        for path in file_paths:   
        path = path.strip()   
        #print (path)
        sr,audio = read(source + path)
        vector   = extract_features(audio,sr)
        log_likelihood = np.zeros(len(models))
        for i in range(len(models)):
            gmm1   = models[i]  #checking with each model one by one
            scores = np.array(gmm1.score(vector))
            log_likelihood[i] = scores.sum()
            log_likelihood1 = (log_likelihood/1000)
            print(log_likelihood1)
        #b.append(log_likelihood1)
        #print(b)
        for a in log_likelihood1[4,]:
            for k in a:
                if k>1.5 and k< -1.5:
                    print(speakers[k])
                else:
                    print("unknown")
```

I want to check each element of 5th array from my threshold value.

Comment: What you want to check? `log_likelihood1[4,]` is a number.

Comment: log_likelihood1[4,] is a number -9.58078621 mentioned in my question. I want to run a loop for these entire array (only for 5th row in my array). and want to check each element of these array with my threshold value?